# Can I add and delete a comment on a group post (and how)?

Tags: facebook

I'm working on an app, and part of it is to make a simple feature that saves some 'favorite' posts, and gives the user the option to see that 'favorite' posts, and write\delete comments to them. I have read a bit the documentation but seems that this option is not there. I was [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-comments/#creating) which simply didn't work when I tried it.

So assume I have the like to some post like `www.facebook.com/{group-id}/permalink/{post-id}` is there a way to add and delete a comment?

I don't care if it will be in JavaScript, Android, iOS or something else. Can I add and delete a comment on a group post (and how)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I assume that you already know you need the permission `user_groups`

I will be using Facebook graph because it's a good for understand what parameters are used

**To add a comment:**

Use this call

```
https://graph.faecbook.com/{group-id}_{post-id}/comments?method=POST&message={Your Messsage}&access_token={An active access token}
```

**To delete a comment:**

*There's two calls for deleting a comment on a group post*

You can use both `{group-id}_{post-id}_{comment_id}` Or `{post-id}_{comment_id}`

The call:

```
https://graph.faecbook.com/{post-id}_{comment_id}?method=DELETE&access_token={An active access token}
```

And the other

```
https://graph.faecbook.com/{group-id}_{post-id}_{comment_id}?method=DELETE&access_token={An active access token}
```

Comment: I know I should do something about the log in, but if you have a link it would be great :)

Comment: You mean User Authentication? [How to Authenticate Users With Facebook Connect](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-your-users-with-facebook-connect/)